# Using GLSL, how to create a perspective bending like effect

Tags: glsl, shader, fragment-shader, perspective

I'm trying to make a perspective bending GLSL shader similar to this.

**Original:**

[image]

**Perspective Bending:**

[image]

```
void mainImage( out vec4 fragColor, in vec2 fragCoord ){

    vec2 uv = fragCoord.xy/iResolution.xy;
    if (uv.x + uv.y < 1.0) uv = 1.0 - vec2(uv.y, uv.x);
    fragColor = texture(iChannel0, uv);

}
```

The code above does not achieve exactly what I want; your help is appreciated!

[image]

Comment: @Rabbid76 Hi, thank you for the quick comment. In fact, I'm really new to the GLSL world. I just want to know where I should start to achieve the perspective bending effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why the line is not at a 45° angle and doesn't end where it should is that by dividing `fragCoord.xy` by `iResolution.xy`, you scale the x and y axes by different amounts. In your situation, since the image is wider than it is tall, `uv` will be stretched horizontally. To avoid that, I suggest you to do the scaling after the mirror transformation :

```
void mainImage( out vec4 fragColor, in vec2 fragCoord ){

    vec2 uv = fragCoord.xy;
    if (uv.x + uv.y < iResolution.y) uv = iResolution.y - vec2(uv.y, uv.x);
    uv /= iResolution.xy;
    fragColor = texture(iChannel0, uv);

}
```

Note that I replaced the `1.0`s by `iResolution.y` since in this coordinate system, that is the height of your image.